# TimeBasedGenerator in UUIDs

Tags: java, uuid

Hi I have the Below Code which giving me error at line :

```
uuidGenerator = Generators.timeBasedGenerator(nic, new UUIDTimer(new Random(), TimestampSynchronizer));
```

Like `TimestampSynchronizer` could not resolve as variable.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.UUID;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.uuid.EthernetAddress;
import com.fasterxml.uuid.Generators;
import com.fasterxml.uuid.TimestampSynchronizer;
import com.fasterxml.uuid.UUIDTimer;
import com.fasterxml.uuid.ext.FileBasedTimestampSynchronizer;
import com.fasterxml.uuid.impl.TimeBasedGenerator;
import com.google.common.base.Charsets;
import com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding;
import com.google.gdata.util.common.util.*;

public class UUID_Test {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
   try {
    UUID_Test.uuidToBase32();
} catch (IOException e) {
    
    e.printStackTrace();
}
  }
 }

 private static String uuidToBase32() throws IOException 
 {
       
        EthernetAddress nic = EthernetAddress.fromInterface();
        TimeBasedGenerator uuidGenerator;   
            uuidGenerator = Generators.timeBasedGenerator(nic, new UUIDTimer(new Random(), TimestampSynchronizer)); 
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[16]);
        bb.putLong(uuidGenerator.generate().getMostSignificantBits());
        bb.putLong(uuidGenerator.generate().getLeastSignificantBits());
        
        return BaseEncoding.base32().encode(bb.array());
    
 
}
}
```

How to solve this?
And when i use

```
   uuidGenerator = Generators.timeBasedGenerator(nic, new UUIDTimer(new Random(), new FileBasedTimestampSynchronizer()));

    Getting Exception
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
```

OR If I write

```
 uuidGenerator = Generators.timeBasedGenerator(nic,new FileBasedTimestampSynchronizer(new File("d://abc"), new File("d://def")));

Getting Exception

WARNING: (file 'd:\abc') Missing or empty file, can not read timestamp value
WARNING: (file 'd:\def') Missing or empty file, can not read timestamp value
WARNING: Could not determine safe timer starting point: assuming current system time is acceptable
GNKOP7JVWII6HMAJ2S7NSZXSYE
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
    at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.checkList(FileLockTable.java:255)
```

Thanks

#### Edit

Code copied from comment to answer:

I place the code in static block

```
static EthernetAddress nic = EthernetAddress.fromInterface();
static File f = new File("D://a.txt");
static File f1 = new File("D://f.txt");
static TimeBasedGenerator uuidGenerator;

static {
    try {
         uuidGenerator = Generators.timeBasedGenerator(nic, new UUIDTimer(new Random(), new FileBasedTimestampSynchronizer(f, f1)));
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Its giving Exception

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to lock 'd://a.txt' (another JVM running UUIDGenerator?)
```

Comment: The Guava tag is irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

TimestampSynchronizer is a non-public class, you can not use that in your code.

The problem with your overlapping lock comes from this line

```
uuidGenerator = Generators.timeBasedGenerator(nic, new UUIDTimer(new Random(), TimestampSynchronizer));
```

You are creating a new generator each time - to ensure the uniqueness of time based UUIDs this uses a lock file. The lock file can only be used for one generator.

Solution: Create just one timer, or even one generator and re-use that inside your loop.

Comment: Hi I have update the code but that way its not. Placing these two lines inside class. static EthernetAddress nic = EthernetAddress.fromInterface();
 static TimeBasedGenerator uuidGenerator= Generators.timeBasedGenerator(nic, new UUIDTimer(new Random(), TimestampSynchronizer));  But this not recognizing  TimestampSynchronizer. Compilation Error

Comment: Yes, please use the FileBasedTimestampSynchronizer - as I mentioned earlier the other one can not be used directly.

Comment: I place the code in static block   static EthernetAddress nic = EthernetAddress.fromInterface();
 static File f = new File("D://a.txt");
 static File f1 = new File("D://f.txt");
 static TimeBasedGenerator uuidGenerator;
 static {
  try {
   uuidGenerator = Generators.timeBasedGenerator(nic, new UUIDTimer(new Random(), new FileBasedTimestampSynchronizer(f, f1)));
  } catch (IOException e) {

   e.printStackTrace();
  } Its giving Exception "java.io.IOException: Failed to lock 'd://a.txt' (another JVM running UUIDGenerator?)"